# Android soft keyboard not displaying

Tags: android

I am trying to write a small app with a WebView, the web view loads a URL which in turn display a HTML form with one input field. The issue I have is the soft keyboard does not display when the HTML input field has focus.

In my MainActivity.java file I have the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String answer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            answer="You are connected to a WiFi Network";
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            answer="You are connected to a Mobile Network";
    }
    else
        answer = "No internet Connectivity";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    WebView webView = (WebView)
            findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

    webView.loadUrl("mydomain.com/index.php");



}
}
```

As I am totally new to android I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Do I need to include code to force a keyboard to display. I have read so many different posts I have lost my way.

Any advice or pointers would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: Tested in device or emulator?

Comment: Hi, testing in device

Comment: do you want to open keyboard when you hit textarea inside the webview.?

Comment: Hi, The web view contains a HTML form with the input field. The FORM is on the server not embedded  in the app.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think webview is not focused. Make the webview focusable after loading.
Set the below params to the webview in XML as well as in the java code.

**XML :**
Set focus params to the webview like below.

```
<WebView
 android:id = "@+id/_webview"
 android:layout_width = "match_parent"
 android:layout_height = "match_parent"
 android:focusable = "true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode = "true">
```

**Java :** 
Set the webviewclient properly and requestfocus.

```
// put under onCreate
homeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
homeWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); // don't forget to prefix http://
homeWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
homeWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUSABLES_ALL);


  private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
  }
```

**NOTE :**  Make sure you added the Internet permission in the Manifest. Without this URL will not be loaded.

Hope you done it... Good Luck.!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help and code. I tried to follow your help/comments but it produces errors. WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); produces: None-Static method cannot be referenced from a static context. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi again, complete the code without errors but sadly still no soft keyboard displaying. Any ideas?

Comment: which device you are using?

Comment: Hi, At the moment I am just testing in the emulator using Nexus s API 15

Comment: ok i tested the above code in device. let me check it in the emulator. I tried using the google.com link. let me get back to u

Comment: can you please try the above code with the google link.? because it works fine in my emulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101477/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-dcjones).